# Custom Jackson Converter not being managed by Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, autowired, spring-data-rest

I am trying to build a custom Jackson deserialization converter with an autowired dependency. I am using Spring boot 2.1.2 along with Spring Data Rest from the Lovelace-SR3 release train. A minimal example application that reproduces the problem is:

**DemoApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        }
}
```

**Config.java**

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean("CurrentDate")
    public Date currentDate() {
            return new Date();
    }
}
```

**TestModelConverter.java**

```
public class TestModelConverter extends StdConverter<TestModel, TestModel> {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("CurrentDate")
    private Date now;

    @Override
    public TestModel convert(TestModel value) {
            value.setNow(now);
            return value;
    }
}
```

**TestModel.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@JsonDeserialize(converter = TestModelConverter.class)
public class TestModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String text;

    private Date now;
}
```

**TestModelRepo.java**

```
public interface TestModelRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<TestModel, Long> { }
```

When deserializing a new `Testmodel`, I would expect `now` to be autowired for use in the deserialization process. Everything I've read points to the [SpringHandlerInstantiator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/SpringHandlerInstantiator.html) being used by default and constructing the `TestModelConverter` in a spring context, thus allowing autowiring of dependencies.

This does not seem to be the case. Autowired dependencies always seem to be `null`